# Passing a list of values (Oracle UserDefinedType) to Oracle stored procedure using Spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, user-defined-types

I am searching for a solution for Passing a list of values (Array or List) to an Oracle Stored Procedure using Spring Boot JPA mechanism.

Here we actually have an Oracle User Defined Type (UDT) which we have to pass via the Spring JPA mechanism. The link [Oracle database object type import in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600155/oracle-database-object-type-import-in-java) is quite old and at that time JPA wasn't supporting Oracle UserDefinedTypes.

I got many examples using the simpler JDBC mechanism, but I could not find much regarding JPA.

[How to pass in array when calling stored procedure with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290149/how-to-pass-in-array-when-calling-stored-procedure-with-spring-data-jpa)

Please anyone let me know if JPA (Spring JPA / Spring Boot JPA) supports this now.

Comment: Using UDT with Java is a bit cumbersome. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-user-defined-types-udt-in-java-db.html I'm using https://jooq.org that has great support for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon, but I'm afraid the solution in the link is for Java and not specifically for Spring JPA. I want to know if JPA specification or Spring JPA has started any support for this.

Comment: UDTs are not supported by JPA because PL/SQL and UDT are not SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks @Simon. Please let me know if you any idea about passing Custom array in place of String array ( check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290149/how-to-pass-in-array-when-calling-stored-procedure-with-spring-data-jpa) to Stored Procedure using the Entity manager approach via Spring JPA

Comment: @SuperMan Did you found any solution to this?